# How to apply tax on order which is programmatically created in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, tax

I am creating an order programmatically in magento but tax is not applied on it. How can i apply tax on order based on address in my script only??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To create an order programmatically in Magento, you need to create the quote first then you can create the order from the quote.
You need to set `setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)` in the quote before you save the quote. This flag will allow Magento auto calculate the tax based on your shipping address.
This article will guide you do it https://jamersan.com/magento-setting-order-quotes-tax-rate-based-on-shipping/

Answer (score 0):

I have found that tax works only when you set '**region_id**' in shipping address, and not with just '**region**'.